# Laravel redirect after log in

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome, authentication, redirect

I noticed some weird behaviour with my `Laravel` applications in `Google Chrome`.

When I want to log in to the application, authentication is successful, but I do not get redirected.

If I check the network tab in developer tools it looks like the request is stalled and it stays that way forever. It doesn't timeout or anything it just stays in the queue.

[image: request status]

If I refresh the page, I get redirected and I am logged in.

This happens only when I try to log in for the first time, it works fine after I log out and try to log in again. Also I noticed this behaviour only in `Google Chrome`.

I am experiancing same behaviour even if I create a brand new project with command:

`laravel new <project_name> --auth`

I found a thread on `Laracasts` forum with same topic but no solution:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-got-stuck-after-login-laravel-58

Does anybody experience similar issues and has a fix for this or at least an explanation of why this is happening? Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I used to have this, it was because of some old cached files try to clear your laravel cache and views, also the browser cache and cookies

Comment: @MohamedMelouk Thans for response. I try in incognito mode and it is the same. I also deleted all laravel cache. As mentioned the same thing happens even if I create a new Laravel project.

Comment: i meen laravel cache using `php artisan config:clear` , `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan optimize`

Comment: @MohamedMelouk I understand. I did this but it still doesn't redirect.